# Perception of progress - number of pages

Tags: checkout, page-layout, progress

I'm at the very beginning of redesigning a checkout/bag page and had a thought about how people perceive their progress through a form based on the amount/lack of pages.

Currently we have a bag page which clicks through to the checkout, the checkout is a single page.

My plan is to merge the two into a single page and integrate the sign in process for users without an account (you need an account to complete the purchase).

Would users feel they are making more progress towards their goal if they navigate from page 1 to page 2 or would the fact they only have to complete actions on a single page to achieve the same goal make it seem quicker for them?

So in short, do I go for two short pages or one long one?

(Page load of the long page isn't an issue, the difference is inperceivable)

Comment: Does your organisation allow for usability testing? That way you could make a small comparative study to answer your research questions.

Comment: @RobE We have done usability testing labs in the past but that was for a huge review. Unfortunately it's not possible for something like this. I had an idea of showing the designs to people inside the business but who have nothing to do with the website/IT to gauge their thoughts - it's a big company so plenty of people about.

Comment: What are you selling, who are your users, how long are the steps (how many fields)? I saw sucessuful 5 steps checkouts, and single page checkouts, all based on extensive UX researches, and built through years.. So it really depends upon context

Answer (score 1):

Use a single page with accordions. This allows the user to get a full overview of where they are but also provides progressive disclosure so that users are not overwhelmed with too much information at once.

[image: accordian design of a savings finder showing some parts open and others shut]

This is discussed more in this question: [When is it bad practice to use an accordion control?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23181/when-is-it-bad-practice-to-use-an-accordion-control)

Comment: Without knowing context for previous question this seems like incorrect answer. (based on my many readings, and to leave at least one reference https://www.borngroup.com/one-page-vs-multi-page-checkout-why-simplicity-is-everything/)